# Changing color of tabs in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have script I created that creates a new sheet, and a new tab in said sheet, before changing the names of said tabs, I want to make it so Sheet1 through Sheet4 all are red.

```
With wbBK2.Sheets(wsWS1).Tab
    .Color = 255
End With
```

Now the code above works for individual tabs, but I am wondering is there a way to change all four tabs at the same time using Excel VBA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
For Each Sht In Application.Worksheets
    With Sht.Tab
        .Color = 255
    End With
Next Sht
```

**Note:**

I think you may be able to change `Application.Worksheets` to `wbBK2.Worksheets`, but I'm running too low on caffeine to remember, or time to test it.

Comment: Works good, but it applies the color to all sheets in a workbook, which doesn't seem to support the OP. Would probably need something like `If sht.Name = "Sheet1" or sht.Name = "Sheet2"...`

Comment: Ah, I was/am under the assumption that the workbook has a total of 4 sheets, and he was looking to change all of them to the color.

Comment: And whadda know ... looks like you were right after all! The beauty of SO... 1,000 ways to interpret the question, 1,000 ways to provide an answer. The benefit is learning for all!

Comment: For anyone else who was wondering about setting RGB values, it would be like the following: `.Color = RGB(255, 110, 110)`.

Answer (score 4):

At first I thought using the `Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2")).Select` method would work, but after testing (and running the macro recorder), I found it didn't.

**Update**

ooo had a great comment. This is cleaner, easier to read way to go:

```
Sub SheetTabColor()

Dim mySheets As Worksheets
Dim mySheet As Worksheet

Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"))

For Each mySheet In mySheets
    mySheet.Tab.Color = 255
Next


End Sub
```

This was my original. Same idea, slightly different method:

```
Sub SheetTabColor()

Dim arrSheets() As String

arrSheets() = Split("Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4", ",")

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(arrSheets()) To UBound(arrSheets())

    Sheets(arrSheets(i)).Tab.Color = 255

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You could still loop the array of sheets though  `Set SelSheets = wbBK2.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet5", "Sheet6")) : For Each sh In SelSheets: sh.Tab.Color = 255:  Next sh`