# Visual Basic, Excel VSTO: Set worksheet tab color

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

All,

I hope this finds you well!

I am currently converting some Visual C# code in a VSTO to Visual Basic and am running into trouble setting Tab.Color for a Worksheet.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
Dim c As Color
c = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

Dim w As Excel.Worksheet
w = Me.Application.Worksheets.Add()
w.Tab.Color = c
```

However, regardless of the value of C, the tab is always black.  This works fine in Visual C# but I haven't been able to figure out the Visual Basic equivalent.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464457/changing-color-of-tabs-in-excel-using-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `w.Tab.Color = &hFF0000`
Colors in VSTO are troublesome. Originally they are in BGR format unlike System.Drawing.Color. So I guess C# handles it somehow.  Anyway, you can use a simple function to convert color from System.Drawing to integer:

```
Function ConvertColor(ByVal color As System.Drawing.Color) As Integer
    Return ((color.B * &h10000) + ((color.G * &h100) + color.R))
End Function
```

Comment: Haven't been able to get this working - tabs still come out as black - thanks though!

Comment: @McThunderThighs I just checked. The code works. And even more, your code works well, too. Maybe you have some other code doing tab color changing (or some experimental add-in you forgot to remove from excel, it happens to me often)

Comment: You're indeed right - `c` was being set to `0` when it fell out of scope, so the tabs were being set to black.