# change color of multiple tabs in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to change the color of certain tabs in my workbook and found basically a possible solution already [here in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464457/changing-color-of-tabs-in-excel-using-vba)

The only problem is, that it doesn't work with me.
I tested it with my original workbook and I created a brand new one which is blank. In both cases it does not work
With a new blank workbook I get a `runtime error 9 "subscript out of range"`, and with my original workbook I get a `runtime error 13 "Type mismatch"`

Code in original workbook:

```
Sub Action_Tabs_red()
Dim tabs As Worksheets
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set tabs = Sheets(Array("cover", "financial overview", "revenues by segments", "Last twelve months"))

For Each ws In tabs
    ws.Tab.Color = 255
Next
End Sub
```

Code in blank file:

```
Sub red()

Dim mySheets As Worksheets
Dim mySheet As Worksheet

Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("Tabelle 1", "Tabelle 2", "Tabelle 3"))

For Each mySheet In mySheets
    mySheet.Tab.Color = 255
Next

End Sub
```

The error always occurs when I set the variable

```
Set tabs = Sheets(Array("cover", "financial overview", "revenues by segments", "Last twelve months"))
```

or

```
Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("Tabelle 1", "Tabelle 2", "Tabelle 3"))
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong, or why these errors occur?

Thanks in advance for your help.

all 3 answers from lturner, MikeD and lenwe helped and did the job. Thanks guys. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer. I used Object since it uses less Bytes.

Comment: Just an FYI in the `For Each` you're still calling `mySheet` instead of `tabs` in your original workbook. This isn't the issue, but look out.

Comment: true, since I deleted and copied the code multiple times, I overlook that. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the `Type Mismatch` error because you're trying to assign data to the `tabs` variable which does not correlate with the `worksheets` collection object.

`Worksheets` is referring to the collection of worksheets within the whole workbook - you cannot use this to refer to your own "array" of worksheets. If you want to declare an array of worksheets, then you will need to declare them as an `Object`.

```
Dim tabs As Object
Dim mySheet As Worksheet

Set tabs = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))

For Each mySheet In tabs
    Debug.Print mySheet.Name
Next mySheet
```

`Subscript out of Range` refers to an object not being able to be found within the collection, using the key provided. Are you sure the sheet names `Array("Tabelle 1", "Tabelle 2", "Tabelle 3")` exist? Should there be the space between `"Tabelle"` and the number? Perhaps it should be `"Tabelle1", "Tabelle2", "Tabelle3"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Dim tabs As Worksheets` with

```
Dim tabs As Sheets
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare MySheets as Variant

```
Sub red()
Dim mySheets As Variant
Dim mySheet As Worksheet

    Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
    For Each mySheet In mySheets
        mySheet.Tab.Color = 255
    Next
End Sub
```

example
[image]