# VBA - Copy a template worksheet and rename with user entered text and amend the tab color

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I would like to (1) copy a template and (2) put it right before an assigned sheet as well as (3) amend its color.

(1) and (2) is fine already, but I have problem on amending the color (which is the last 3 row of the code), may I seek your help to have a look..? Thanks in advance for your help, it's much appreciated!

Sub Add_ITS()

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wt As Worksheet: Set wt = wb.Sheets("Data Input-ITS template")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("ITSEnd")
Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String

xst = False
newname = Application.InputBox("Please Enter the name of the Worksheet")
If newname = "False" Then Exit Sub
For Each sh In wb.Sheets
    If sh.Name = newname Then
        xst = True: Exit For
    End If
Next
If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
    info = "Sheet name is invalid. Please retry."
    GoTo retry
End If
wt.Copy before:=ws: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname

With wb.newws.Tab
.Color = 6299648
.TintAndShade = 0

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing color of tabs in Excel using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464457/changing-color-of-tabs-in-excel-using-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `Workbook` as you already declared this when you set the object variable of `newws` (it is the `ActiveWorkbook` as you set `newws` as `ActiveSheet`). Try removing `wb`:

```
With newws.Tab
    .Color = 6299648
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.Color` property then you should put sth like `vbRed`, `vbBlue` and so on or RGB values (below).

If you want to use values in numeric format try property `.ColorIndex` (values between 0-56) or `RGB`(integer 0-255 [red], integer 0-255[green], integer 0-255 [blue])

For example:

```
.ColorIndex=23
.Color = RGB(111, 233, 233)
```

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, it's much easier to locate the specific colour if I use this format, thank you!!